# Bootstrap Table - About server side pagination

Tags: javascript, datatables, bootstrap-table

I use server-side pagination but when I activated server side pagination, also data search filter works in server side mode.

It's possible to configure search filter to work in client mode only on current displayed page?

```
Server Side:
http://jsfiddle.net/4r6g4cfu/3/light/
```

Thanks
T.